# Comparison of object with fixnum

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to compare objects with fixnums.

```
class Dog
  include Comparable
  def <=>(other)
    1
  end
end
```

Given the class above, why does this work:

```
dog = Dog.new
array = [2, 1, 4, dog]
array.min
=> 1
```

But this does not:

```
dog = Dog.new
array = [dog, 2, 1, 4]
array.min
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Dog failed
    from (irb):11:in `each'
    from (irb):11:in `min'
    from (irb):11
```

When the object is the first element, why can't I compare the object with the numbers?
Is there any way I can solve this issue? I want the Dog object to always be the greatest value when it's compared with any other value in the array, which is why I've set it to 1 in <=> method.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `dog < 1` works, but `1 < dog` fails. Maybe you need to override `Fixnum#<=>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare against numeric types, you can implement [`coerce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce):

```
class Dog
  include Comparable

  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @age <=> other
  end

  def coerce(numeric)
    [numeric, @age]
  end
end

Dog.new(5) <=> Dog.new(5)  #=>  0
Dog.new(5) <=> 1           #=>  1
         1 <=> Dog.new(5)  #=> -1

[1, 3, Dog.new(2)].sort
#=> 1, #<Dog @age=2>, 3]
```

The above sorting can be achieved without implementing `<=>` and `coerce` using [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end

[1, 3, Dog.new(2)].sort_by { |obj| obj.is_a?(Dog) ? obj.age : obj }
#=> 1, #<Dog @age=2>, 3]
```

There's also [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) and [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: I couldn't submit this from my mobile.. Damn.. :-)

Comment: @ssks replace `@age` with `Float::INFINITY`

Comment: BINGO!! Uri and Stefan - thank you both! I've set @age to Float::INFINITY and its doing just the job. To confirm, coerce allows you to flip the comparison relationship so object <=> fixnum AND fixnum <=> object - is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ssks `coerce` is called by Numeric's methods whenever an argument is incompatible. In `1 + Dog.new(5)` the argument to `:+` (`Dog.new(5)`) is incompatible, so `Dog.new(5).coerce(1)` is called which returns `[1, 5]`. Now both arguments are compatible and `1 + 5` can be evaluated: the result is `6`. This is all done from within Numeric's methods, no magic involved :-)

Comment: ok great, this is really interesting.. So without coerce, an object and fixnum are not compatible to be compared against one another, even though in our <=> method, we define the numeric value inside @age to be the number we use to compare all other fixnums against. Why is the coerce array [numeric, @age] arranged in this particular order? If it was flipped around how would it affect the result?

Comment: [`<=>`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Numeric.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) is just a method with an argument, `1 <=> dog` is equivalent to  `1.send(:<=>, dog)`. Numeric can decide what to do with `dog`. If it determines that `dog` is incompatible, `dog.coerce(1)` is called and returns `[1, 5]`. Note that this is the same order as the original `1 <=> dog`. Flipping the values would probably result in either an inverted result or a recursion (try it!). Numeric uses `coerce` internally to cast numbers into the same type/class, e.g. `1.coerce(2.5)` returns `[2.5, 1.0]`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to allow for `Dog` to be compared with `Fixnum` you need to implement the comparison on `Fixnum` as well:

```
class Fixnum
  alias :my_compare :'<=>'
  def <=>(other)
    if other.is_a? Dog
      return -1
    end
    my_compare(other)
  end
end

array.min
# => 1

array.max
# => #<Dog:0x8f712fc>
```

Comment: I was reading about #coerce - is this not suitable for this kind of situation?

Comment: your suggested solution above works, thank you! I was just wondering about the #coerce method... I was doing some reading about it before I posted my issue here. To be honest, I didn't really understand the concept behind coerce and how it is used in this kind of situation. Like, how coerce could help convert an object into something comparable with a fixnum and vice versa.

Comment: @ssks didn't see your comments, I've just posted an answer using `coerce`

Answer (score 0):

That is because `<=>` is not a binary relation in the mathematical sense (i.e., defined on *A*^2 for some set *A*), but is a method on an object, and is not symmetric. Allowing `other` in `Foo#<=>(other)` to be an instance of `Bar` does not mean that `other` in `Bar#<=>(other)` can be `Foo`.